# SQL subgroups from one table in one query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a category table with countries, states, regions, towns each with a respective type. An item's parent is the region, state, or country it's located in. Then there's a table with objects having those id's. Specific categories and objects might be published or not.

```
table: category
id  title       parent  type    published
75  Spain       0       1       1
76  Mallorca    75      2       1
144 North       76      3       1
149 South       76      3       1
148 East        76      3       1
147 West        76      3       1
170 Cala        144     4       1
195 Puebla      144     4       0
166 Pica        149     4       1
189 Playa       148     4       0
199 Santa Ana   148     4       1
247 Puerto      147     4       1
...

table: objects
id  title       country_id      state_id    region_id   town_id     published
4   Alba        75              76          149         195         1
5   Gris        75              76          144         170         1
8   Casa        75              76          148         199         1
8   Pueblo      75              76          147         247         1
8   Don Carlo   75              76          148         199         1
...
```

The result should be a list of names grouped by category type with the correct number of objects in each country, state, region, town.

```
id      title       parent     type         obj_count
75      Spain       0           1           12
76      Mallorca    75          2           4
144     North       76          3           2
149     South       76          3           3
148     East        76          3           0
147     West        76          3           1
170     Cala        144         4           0
166     Pica        149         4           1
189     Playa       148         4           0
195     Puebla      144         4           1
247     Puerto      147         4           1
199     Santa Ana   148         4           2
and so on...
```

The query I have so far returns a full list of names in the right order but only a full count (including unpublished) for the towns, but once I try to check for 'WHERE ob.published = 1 AND c.published = 1' it only returns the towns, not the countries, states, or regions.

```
SELECT 
c.id as id, c.title as title, c.type as type, c.parent as parent,
count(ob.town_id) as obj_count

FROM category AS c
LEFT JOIN category AS r       ON c.id = r.parent
LEFT JOIN category AS u       ON r.id = u.parent
LEFT JOIN category AS o       ON u.id = o.parent

LEFT JOIN objects AS ob       ON ob.town_id = c.id

WHERE 1
GROUP BY type, id, parent
ORDER BY parent, title
```

Can anyone help me to do this in one query? Thank you.

Comment: On basis of id you need to count?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT c.id, c.title, c.type, count(c.id) as cnt 
FROM category c 
LEFT JOIN objects o ON (o.country_id = c.id  OR o.state_id = c.id OR o.region_id = c.id OR o.town_id = c.id) 
GROUP BY c.id 
ORDER by type
```